# First OOP TicTacToe game

Tags: c++, beginner, game, tic-tac-toe

This is my first program using classes. How could this be improved?

```
#include <iostream>

class TicTacToe
{
    char m_field[3][3];
    char sign;
public:
    char Sign(char x) {sign=x;};
    void MakeField();
    void DrawField();
    bool IsFree(int y, int x);
    bool FindAndReplace(int x,int y);
    bool Row();
    bool Column();
    bool Diagonal();
    bool Win();
    bool IsFull();
    TicTacToe(){MakeField();DrawField();}
};

void TicTacToe::MakeField()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                m_field[i][j]=' ';
    }

void TicTacToe::DrawField()
    {
        std::cout << " ";
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            std::cout << " " << i;

        std::cout << "\n  - - -\n";
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            std::cout << i;
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                std::cout << "|" << m_field[i][j];
            }
            std::cout << "|\n  - - -\n";
        }
    }

bool TicTacToe::IsFree(int y, int x)
    {
        if(m_field[y][x]==' ')
            return true;
        return false;
    }

bool TicTacToe::FindAndReplace(int x,int y)
    {
        if(IsFree(y,x))
        {
            m_field[y][x]=sign;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

bool TicTacToe::Row()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            if(!IsFree(i,0)&&!IsFree(i,1)&&!IsFree(i,2))
            if(m_field[i][0]==m_field[i][1]&&m_field[i][0]==m_field[i][2])
                return true;
        return false;
    }

bool TicTacToe::Column()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            if(!IsFree(0,i)&&!IsFree(1,i)&&!IsFree(2,i))
            if(m_field[0][i]==m_field[1][i]&&m_field[0][i]==m_field[2][i])
                return true;
        return false;
    }

bool TicTacToe::Diagonal()
    {
        if(!IsFree(1,1))
        {
            if(m_field[2][0]==m_field[1][1]&&m_field[1][1]==m_field[0][2])
                return true;
                if(m_field[0][0]==m_field[1][1]&&m_field[0][0]==m_field[2][2])
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

bool TicTacToe::Win()
    {
        return Row()||Column()||Diagonal();
    }

bool TicTacToe::IsFull()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                if(IsFree(i,j))
                    return false;
        return true;
    }

int main()
{
    int x,y,i=0;
    char sign;
    TicTacToe field;
    while(!field.IsFull())
    {
        i++;
        sign=i%2==0?'o':'x';
        std::cout << "Turn " << sign << ": Get x cordinate:";
        std::cin >> x;
        std::cout << "Get y cordinate:";
        std::cin >> y;
        if(x>2||y>2)
        {
            std::cout << "this coordinates does not exist! Try again\n";
            i--;
            continue;
        }

        field.Sign(sign);
        if(field.FindAndReplace(x,y))
            field.DrawField();
        else
        {
            std::cout << "is full!";
            i--;
        }
        if(field.Win())
        {
            std::cout << "Winned sign " << sign;
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\nEnd!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Some comments on naming and coding style.

First, it is a bit unusual for member function names to be in PascalCase in C++. camelCase or `snake_case` are more usual, reserving identifiers that start with an uppercase letter for type names.

```
char sign;
char Sign(char x) {sign=x;};
field.Sign(sign);
```

This isn't clear to me at all (could be a language issue though). What is this "sign" thing? Positive/negative? Does the `Sign` method do a cryptographic signature? What does `Sign` do to a `sign`?

I'd go with `player`, and rename `TicTacToe::Sign` to `SetPlayer`/`SetCurrentPlayer` to make it clear it's setting something.

Or get rid of that entirely and pass the current player's symbol to the methods that need it: there's only one. This lets the TicTacToe class to only manage the board, and leaves managing players to your future gameplay controller class ('cos stuffing all that in `main` isn't the best idea).

```
void MakeField();
```

The field is already "made", but not initialized. Something like `InitializeField` or `ClearBoard` would be sound more appropriate to me (though that's really minor).

```
void DrawField();           // good
bool IsFree(int y, int x);  // great
```

```
bool FindAndReplace(int x,int y);
```

This method doesn't find anything. It sets a cell to a value if it's free. And wait a sec, didn't we just see another method that takes coordinates?

```
bool IsFree        (int y, int x);  // oh?
bool FindAndReplace(int x, int y);  // what?
```

Why do you pass in the coordinates in different order? Please don't do that, it is very, very error prone. Stick to one order, and make that `x, y` consistently.

```
bool Row();
bool Column();
bool Diagonal();
```

These names don't tell me anything about what the functions do. I'd expect them to somehow *return* are row, column or diagonal, but `bool` doesn't work for any of this. Plus they operate on all rows, columns and diagonals (plural).

I'd rename all that to `CheckRows()` etc., and make them private - users aren't supposed to call these directly. Then fix the indentation, especially since you're not using `{}` in your `if`s - your current layout is misleading.

```
bool Win();
```

`IsGameWon()`?

```
bool IsFull();
```

`IsGameTied()`?

```
TicTacToe(){MakeField();DrawField();}
```

The constructor initializes the field - that's good, but then it prints it immediately. This might not be what the caller wants, and the caller doesn't have a choice. I'd remove the `DrawField()` call, and add some whitespace.

```
TicTacToe() { MakeField(); }
```

Now in `main`, this should be in a separate function that does just that, i.e. get valid input from the player.

```
    std::cout << "Turn " << sign << ": Get x cordinate:";
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "Get y cordinate:";
    std::cin >> y;
    if(x>2||y>2)
    {
        std::cout << "this coordinates does not exist! Try again\n";
        i--;
        continue;
    }
```

The `i--; continue;` is not very intuitive, and you're likely to get something wrong if you ever update the code and add something in between the top of the loop and the `continue` statement.

I personally don't like this form:

```
    if(field.FindAndReplace(x,y))
        field.DrawField();
    else
    {
        std::cout << "is full!";
        i--;
    }
```

I'd `{}` both sides, and only omit the braces only if both sides are single, simple statements. Most importantly be consistent - your `Row`, `Col` and `Diagonal` methods aren't (for the `for`).

As for spacing:

```
    sign=i%2==0?'o':'x';
```

This is unreadable for me (slightly better if I put my glasses on, but still hard to parse). More spaces, at least:

```
    sign = i%2==0 ? 'o' : 'x';
```

And I'd personally add a pair of parens and even more spaces, but I tend to like parens more than most I think.

```
    sign = (i % 2 == 0) ? 'o' : 'x';
```

Same applies for most of your assignments and comparisons, they could do with more spaces (and perhaps more parens), e.g.

```
if (!IsFree(0, i) && !IsFree(1, i) && !IsFree(2, i))
if ((m_field[0][i] == m_field[1][i]) && (m_field[0][i] == m_field[2][i]))
m_field[y][x] = sign;
```

Finally:

```
bool TicTacToe::Something()
    {
    }
```

but:

```
int main()
{
}
```

That's unusual. I'd stick to one style only - the class/struct name already informs the reader that it's a member function, so I see no reason for a different style between toplevel and member functions. (I'd pick the style you chose for `main`, less wasted horizontal space.)

---

A couple suggestions for the code itself.

This one is (I believe) non controversial:

```
bool TicTacToe::IsFree(int y, int x)
{
  // no need for an 'if', you have a boolean result already
  return m_field[y][x] == ' ';
}
```

This is a bit trickier but makes your row and column check a bit easier to read:

```
bool TicTacToe::CheckRows()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (IsFree(i, 0)) // if the first cell is free, no need to look further
      continue;
    if ((m_field[i][0] == m_field[i][1]) && (m_field[i][0] == m_field[i][2]))
      return true; // and if it isn't the other two must match to win
  }
  return false;
}
```

This is a matter of taste - getting the "easy" cases out of the way as soon as possible generally results in less nesting depths for the main part of the function. (Here, not much gained.)

```
bool TicTacToe::SetIfFree(int x, int y)
{
  if (!IsFree(y, x))
    return false;

  m_field[y][x] = sign;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: `whatever_this_is_called` is frequently referred to as [Snake Case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case).

Comment: Thanks @glampert. Edited in (and added another remark I hadn't spotted).